# Pelican Plugin - How to add context variables?

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I am making a pelican plugin and I'm having trouble adding variables to the templates.

For example in my plugin's code:

```
def baz(generator):
    generator.foo = 'bar'

def register():
    signals.generator_init.connect(baz)
```

And in my templates I have:

```
<h1>lorem - {{foo}}</h1>
```

And I would expect `lorem - bar` to show in the `<h1>`.

I have been looking at https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/807b3bced38bff7b83a2efa2ce8cda9d644ebad3/pelican/generators.py trying to see how I can add this as an environment variable to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I needed was

```
generator.context['foo'] = 'bar'
```